# Access Code Error

Tags: ms-access

I have a form setup where I can add data to a table in access. I have spaces for the data entry and then an "Add" Button to add the data. But whenever I run it I get the error: Run Time Error 424 Object Required.

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
'when we click on button Add there are two options
'1. For insert
'2. For Update
If Me.txt_code.Tag & "" = "" Then
    'this is for insert new
'add data to table
CurrentDb.Execute = "INSERT INTO KWTable(KW, Source, Code) " & _
" VALUES(" & Me.text_key & ",'" & Me.txt_code & "','" & _
Me.combo_source & "')"
Else
'otherwise (Tag of txtID store the id of student to be modified)
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE KWTable " & _
" SET KW=" & Me.text_key & _
", Code='" & Me.txt_code & "'" & _
", Source='" & Me.combo_source & "'" & _
" WHERE KW=" & Me.text_key
End If
'clear form
cmdClear_Click
'refresh data in list on form
TableSub.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: is CodeStorage even defined?

Comment: Can you give a little more information? what is the code you use to add the data? Is CodeStorage defined as string?

Answer (score 2):

`Execute` is a method.  Don't try to set it equal to something.  Discard the `=` sign.

```vb
CodeStorage.Execute "INSERT INTO KWTable(KW, Source, Code) " & _
    " VALUES(" & Me.text_key & ",'" & Me.txt_code & "','" & _
    Me.combo_source & "')"
```

That could work assuming `CodeStorage` is a valid DAO.Database.  If you get another error, tell us about `CodeStorage` and whether your `INSERT` statement works if you save the SQL to a new query in the query designer.

```vb
Dim strInsert As String
strInsert = "INSERT INTO KWTable(KW, Source, Code) " & _
    " VALUES(" & Me.text_key & ",'" & Me.txt_code & "','" & _
    Me.combo_source & "')"
Debug.Print strInsert
CodeStorage.Execute strInsert
```

Then you can examine the completed `INSERT` statement in the Immediate window.  You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> to go there.

In a comment you reported `CodeStorage` is actually a table.  A table doesn't have an `Execute` method.  Use `Execute` from a `DAO.Database` object such as `CurrentDb`.

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute strInsert
```

Comment: I did get the same error. CodeStorage is the table that houses all the data. The three columns are KW, Source, Code.

Comment: I revised the answer based on that information.  However I'm confused why you wanted to use one table, `CodeStorage`, to `INSERT` into another table, `KWTable`.  I suspect there is something more here which I don't understand.

Comment: I changed the CodeStorage to CurrentDB and that resolved that issue, but now i have the error: COMPILE ERROR: ARGUMENT NOT OPTIONAL and the Private Suv cmdAdd_Click() title is highlighted now.

Comment: And it is saying there are too few parameters

Comment: Seems you're now talking about code you haven't shown us, so I'm handicapped.  However, if you actually have `Private Suv` in the procedure declaration, change it to `Private Sub`

Comment: Ok the code has been fixed as far as the spelling is. I edited the above message to include the whole code. And it is now giving me the same compile error.